# fragment does not go to activity [Android]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

It's been less than a week since I learned Android. trying to create a project, but there are some things that don't work.

**Problem**: Does not move from fragment to activity

**Tried**: Browse the document on Google. and I used @Override for `onclickListener` in `HomeFragment.java` A red line popped up and woke up remove, but still don't know what the error is.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private Button btn_today;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        ViewGroup root_view = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        Button btn_today = (Button)root_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_today);

        btn_today.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }


}
```

used the **Navigation Drawer Activity** when I first **created the project**.

what `I want to do is click on the button btn_today to go to the activity page (in xml file)`

I'm a beginner or I don't know what the problem is. appreciate any help
doing it all day, but I'm not sure.

Comment: At the moment, what happens if you click the button? Do you get a null pointer exception?

Comment: use Button btn_today = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.btn_today); as you are returning root on onCreateView()

Comment: Sanjid Chowdhury // There was no action on your value when you clicked the button. But I've solved it Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be use root variable for finding button view id.

```
Button btn_today = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.btn_today);
```